# Dados de notificação PagSeguro

Tags: python

Estou tentando integrar o PagSeguro com essa lib:

```
https://github.com/rochacbruno/python-pagseguro
```

Mas, não consigo acessar os dados de notificação que o Pagseguro me envia.
Estou usando o seguinte código:

```
notification_code = request.POST['notificationCode']
pg = PagSeguro(email="filipe.ferminiano@gmail.com", token="token")
notification_data = pg.check_notification(notification_code)
print notification_data['status']
```

Na última linha eu recebo o erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'PagSeguroNotificationResponse' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que li da biblioteca, o método `check_notification` retorna um objeto do tipo `PagSeguroNotificationResponse`.

Observe o método `parse_xml` dessa classe:

```
def parse_xml(self, xml):
    try:
        parsed = xmltodict.parse(xml, encoding="iso-8859-1")
    except Exception as e:
        logger.debug(
            "Cannot parse the returned xml '{0}' -> '{1}'".format(xml, e)
        )
        parsed = {}

    transaction = parsed.get('transaction', {})
    for k, v in transaction.iteritems():
        setattr(self, k, v)
```

É criado um campo para cada atributo do XML lido. Portanto, o que você quer, na verdade, é:

```
print notification_data.status
```

Answer (score 0):

Tem um detalhe:

O XML que o PagSeguro retorna tem vários "níveis", portanto, o objeto `PagSeguroNotificationResponse` realmente terá os atributos correspondentes com o XML, mas com uma ressalva:

A partir do segundo nível eles permanecerão como dicionários, por exemplo, usando o nome do seu objeto:

`notification_data.status` # retorna o numero do status

`notification_data.shipping` # retorna um dicionário, onde todas as propriedades a partir daqui terão de ser acessadas através de chave ex.: `notification_data.shipping['address']` e se quiser o nome da rua por ex.: `notification_data.shipping['address']['street']`